# Setting a field search variable after main entries variable changes values

Tags: search, field

Kind of hard to explain but here's an example:

```
{{entries.all()|length}} {# outputs 88 #}

{% set hasTopic = entries.search('dataTable_topic:*').all() %}
{{entries|length}} {# outputs 7 #}
```

How can I keep `entries` the same below the search variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the way Element queries are in Craft 3.

In Craft 2, each time you called a setter method (`search()` here) it would clone your `ElementCriteriaModel`, use that value **on the clone** and return the cloned object leaving the original alone.

In Craft 3, when you call a setter method, it gets set on the current element query.

So if I understood correctly, you should use `clone` ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/functions.html#clone)):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries().section('yourSection') %}
{{entries.all()|length}}

{% set hasTopic = clone(entries).search('dataTable_topic:*').all() %}
{{entries|length}} | {{ hasTopic|length }}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it